Getting an error setting up sentry for react-native project
followed the sentry documentation
executed this command in the project directory "npx @sentry/wizard@latest -s -i reactNative".
and got this error
▲  Something went wrong
node:fs:2352
return binding.writeFileUtf8(
^
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/aryan/Workspace/mobileapp/sentry-wizard-installation-error-1723540292880.log'
at Object.writeFileSync (node:fs:2352:20)
at /Users/aryankushwaha/.npm/_npx/ddb126e78325956c/node_modules/@sentry/wizard/dist/src/utils/clack-utils.js:406:52
at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:430:5)
at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:519:28)
at ChildProcess.emit (node:domain:488:12)
at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1105:16)
at Socket. (node:internal/child_process:457:11)
at Socket.emit (node:events:519:28)
at Socket.emit (node:domain:488:12)
at Pipe. (node:net:337:12) {
errno: -2,
code: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'open',
path: '/Users/aryan/Workspace/mobileapp/sentry-wizard-installation-error-1723540292880.log'
}
Node.js v21.3.0
was expecting the setup to be done successfully.

Hi, please see formatting help

Hi Aryan,
could you share the whole Sentry Wizard output (text or screenshot) and the version of the Wizard you've used?
From the stack trace it looks like a package installation failed. This might be for multiple reasons, so we need more information to debug it.
Disclaimer: I work for Sentry.
Feel free to open issue at https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-wizard/issues
